# Command not working

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Today I started on my first big project, which is a Minecraft Spigot plugin for my server called Pixel Network. When creating the `/help` command I encountered a problem. Whenever I called the command it just returned itself. I know that this is a question frequently asked, but I just couldn't get it to work. Here is my code:

Main Class

```
package gq.pixelnetwork.main;

import gq.pixelnetwork.listeners.CommandListener;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable() {
        System.out.println("If you see this, the Pixel Network plugin is loaded!");
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new CommandListener(), this);
    }

    public void onDisable() { System.out.println("If you see this, the Pixel Network plugin is unloaded!"); }
}
```

And my Command Listener Class

```
package gq.pixelnetwork.listeners;

import gq.pixelnetwork.modules.Colors;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CommandListener implements Listener{
    Colors c = new Colors();

    // Returning false will return the command to the sender!
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
            if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                sender.sendMessage(c.red + "This is a Player-only command!");

                return true;
            } else{
                openHelp();

                return true;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void openHelp() {
        Inventory helpGUI = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 27, "§a§lHelp Menu");
        createDisplay(Material.BOOK, helpGUI, 11, "§7/spawn", "§fUse it to get to Spawn.");
        createDisplay(Material.BOOK, helpGUI, 13, "§7/hub", "§fUse it to get to HUB.");
        createDisplay(Material.BOOK, helpGUI, 15, "§7/help", "§fUse it to see this menu.");
    }

    private static void createDisplay(Material material, Inventory inv, int Slot, String name, String lore) {
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(material);
        ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName(name);
        ArrayList<String> Lore = new ArrayList<String>();
        Lore.add(lore);
        meta.setLore(Lore);
        item.setItemMeta(meta);

        inv.setItem(Slot, item);

    }
}
```

The reference to the Colors class is not the problem, as that is just a small 'module' I have made to make using colors easier.

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance,
- Xaaf

Comment: What do you mean 'returns itself'?

Comment: You just get the command `/help` sent in chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the Spigot API has changed significantly since I've used it, your problem is that you're using onCommand in an event handler, not in your JavaPlugin class.

For example, you can have something like this

```
public class Whatever extends JavaPlugin {
  @Override
  public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
    if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("hello")){
        sender.sendMessage("Hello!");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  } 
}
```

Which will work fine, but you're registering your CommandListener as an Event Listener, meaning that when bukkit parses the class, it looks for any methods with an @EventHandler annotation and processes them as an event when they're fired.

You can also a Command Executor, which would look something like this:

```
public class Whatever extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable(){
        this.getCommand("test").setExecutor(new MyCommandExecutor(this));
        // register the class MyCommandExecutor as the executor for the "test" command
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDisable(){

    }

}
```

then have another class like so:

```
public class MyCommandExecutor implements CommandExecutor {
    private final Whatever plugin;

    public MyPluginCommandExecutor(Whatever plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin; // Store the plugin in situations where you need it.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("test")){
            sender.sendMessage("Hello World!");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Essentially, you're trying to implement a CommandExecutor inside an EventListener, which shouldn't work, as far as I'm aware.

You're also returning true by default if the command isn't the one your plugin is handling, which is wrong, you should return false if it's not your command.

Comment: Hey Zack,
I have tried adding the @EventHandler, which didn't work. Isn't it that when you are using a Command Executor that you have to put in each individual command? Because that would be annoying for a big plugin like this will be.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be, you can have either: one CommandExecutor per command in the plugin, one large onCommand method that acts as the CommandExecutor for your entire Plugin.  You wouldn't have an @EventHandler above an onCommand method, because it's not an event

Comment: How would I use the OnCommand method I have as the large commandExecutor then? I am really lost in this one...

Comment: Change your class to be like [this](https://gist.github.com/zack6849/7f5ee164a85399acfa42c0e7f4322732)

Comment: But then I'd have to put every command I create in a new Executor in the Main class. I don't want that, because it has to be done individually for every single one...

Comment: You can have multiple checks in one executor, i did so in the example provided